# Using node to stream file contents to stdout

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

My NodeJS application is using pino for JSON based logging. Pino sends the log file to stdout. I'm simply saving the output to a file using  ./app.js >> filename.log . I want to setup a small script that will constantly stream the log file similar to the -f flag on tail. I do not want the application to exit when it reaches the end of the file, but rather wait for additional data to be streamed. I can get the file to echo to stdout but either it does not continue the stream once it reaches the end of the file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const split = require('split2')
const pump = require('pump')

// Attempt 1 
fs.createReadStream(file)
  .pipe(split(JSON.parse))
  .on('data', function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  })

pump(process.stdout, streamToElastic);

// Attempt 2
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(logFileLocation);
pump(readStream.pipe(process.stdout), split(JSON.parse));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement it yourself, since built-in streams do not provide that functionality, you have to watch for file changes, or poll the file.

You can use one of this packages that implement that already:

- [tail](https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail)
- [tailing-stream](https://github.com/jasontbradshaw/tailing-stream)

Using `tail`:

```
Tail = require('tail').Tail;

tail = new Tail("fileToTail");

tail.on("line", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

tail.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log('ERROR: ', error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the accepted answer, this worked fine for me:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const process = require('process');

lf = fs.createReadStream(tailfile);
lf.on('open', () => { lf.pipe(process.stdout); });
```

Comment: Or simply `fs.createReadStream(tailfile).pipe(process.stdout)`